# Jquery slideshow tweaks

Tags: jquery, slideshow

I am trying to run a jQuery slideshow, [here it is](http://jsfiddle.net/ZLMez/).

I need to

1. Auto play the slide show
2. The slideshow is using a crossfade transition. I need the slides moving to the left/right and fading out and the new slide moving/fading in. If you click on the right arrow, the current slide should move to the left and fade out, and the new slide would come in from the right and fade in.

What tweaks needs to be done? Any clue?

Answer (score 0):

Go to the plugin's website and look for the options for the slideshow and how to implement them (usually it's very easy to do so). the same goes for the other effects you're looking for. If this plugin doesn't have the required options, than I'd suggest you try something else that would satisfy your needs. Of course, you could try and tweak the source yourself, but with so many other free alternatives, it's not the most efficient way to go.